# environment variables set in bash

Tags: path, bashrc

Team,

I have Veritas product installed. When I try to run the `veritas` commands, I have to use the original path (i.e. `/opt/VRTS/bin`). Instead of that, can we add the path into our bash profile. I tried it but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: If you added it to your PATH variable, did you run `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: and can you show *how* you added it to the bash profile?

Comment: wow. source .bash_profile worked. is there no impact for other OS commands rht?.

Comment: No, when you use source, your reloading/refreshing your bash_profile

Comment: No, `source .bash_profile` is reloading the edited `.bash_profile` in your current session.  You could achieve the same by logging out and then back in to the system after editing `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2):

Making modifications to your bash_profile requires you to run source to refresh so the changes take effect:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/etc/environment`

1. Add your variable to `/etc/environment`
   Example:

   TEST="testing"
2. Logout from current user and login again

Comment: I'll give a try.